# How do I apply present working properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have trouble in my application with swift 4.
I'd like to move my view controller automatically when my string get a value without nil. (Promatically)

However it does not work at all.

```
if(rst_str != nil){
    let nextView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewListController") as! ViewListController

    //viewListController.delegate = self;

    print("log storyboard");

    self.present(nextView, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

The message of "log storyboard" is printed normally.
However the line of self.present is not working at all.

How can I resolve from my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
 self.present(nextView, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

won't work in 2 cases

1- the current vc you run this line in is currently not fully laid - out such as making it in `viewDidLoad`

2- the current vc is currently presenting another vc